# how to import module from other directory in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

This is my directory tree

```
Game/
   a/
      1.py
      ...
   b/
      2.py
```

In 2.py I want import function display from 1.py. First I keep both file in same folder there is no problem.But how to import from other location?

Comment: @Haidro similar but i am looking for simple method(without create distutils packages).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [imp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html).

```py
import imp
foo = imp.load_source('filename', 'File\Directory\filename.py')
```

This is just like importing normally. You can then use the file. For example, if that file contains `method()`, you can call it with `foo.method()`.

You can also try this.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('folder_name')
```

Comment: plus one for `sys.path.append('folder_name')`

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

Add another folder to `sys.path` and import it by name

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../a')

import mod1
# you need to add `__init__.py` to `../a` folder
# and rename `1.py` to `mod1.py` or anything starts with letter
```

Or create distutils package and than you will be able to make relative imports like

```
 from ..a import mod1
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `__init__.py` file in any directory you want to import from and then you have 2 options;

e.g. Your code will now look like this:

```
Game/
   __init__.py
   a/
      __init__.py
      1.py
      ...
   b/
      __init__.py
      2.py
```

1. If your `Game` folder is in your PYTHONPATH you can now do `from Game.a import 1` in `2.py` or vice versa in `1.py`
2. `from ..a import 1` which is [relative import](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)