# Python: import from other directory - name is not defined

Tags: python

I looked to several related questions:

[Importing python file from other directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271248/importing-python-file-from-other-directory)

and

[how to import module from other directory in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875840/how-to-import-module-from-other-directory-in-python)

but they do not really solve my problems.

So I have

```
|-1.py
|-my_app
  |-a.py
  |-b.py
```

From `1.py` I did:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert (0, './my_app/')
from a import *
```

and I have the error: `name a is not defined`.

How could I call the class and functions I defined in `a.py` and `b.py` from `1.py`?

Many thanks

Comment: Hello @mommomonthewind you can try to use [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) or try this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#standard-modules)...Thankss

Comment: Try `from my_app.a import *`

Comment: It does not work :( @bleand

Comment: You should also do what @blhsing suggested to make it work

Comment: Why python has made simple import stuff from a relative path so complex? There are many Q on different portal and chain of complex solutions. In other C++, Java etc it is straight forward approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have an `__init__.py` file (it can be empty) under the `my_app` directory for it to be an importable package.